# Error on the first run on vagrant laravel

Tags: laravel, yaml, vagrant, virtual-machine

Im trying to run vagrant laravel but im getting an error on my first run on the VM, did i do something wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    17: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/bin/vagrant:194:in `<main>'
    16: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/bin/vagrant:194:in `new'
    15: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize'
    14: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:974:in `process_configured_plugins'
    13: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:793:in `vagrantfile'
    12: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:793:in `new'
    11: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:29:in `initialize'
    10: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
     9: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'
     8: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
     7: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'
     6: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
     5: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
     4: from C:/Users/awthz/Homestead/Vagrantfile:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
     2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
     1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse': (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 13 column 12 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

can anybody point me to whats happening would be very much appreciated.

Comment: did you look at this? psych.rb:456:in `parse': (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 13 column 12 (Psych::SyntaxError). It looks like there is an extra escape char in the code.

Comment: i tried and its not letting me edit the file, or even save it..

Answer (score 2):

Open the vagrant file `C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/bin/vagrant` and add these two lines after the opening Shebang String (`"#!/usr/bin/env ruby"`).

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')
```

Comment: its not letting me edit the file. Is there any specific ide that i will be able to save this? or do i need to restart my computer so that the vagrant is not running? sorry just new with this.

Comment: @awthzZei what Operation System you working?

Comment: @awthzZei https://groups.google.com/g/vagrant-up/c/R2gPXfXxnGQ?pli=1

Comment: currently using Windows 11.

Comment: @awthzZei https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yio0IYrZhtw

Comment: Thanks, im able to edit the file however, the error was still there after the edit.

Comment: @awthzZei are you restarted?

Comment: Seems like my path on the yaml file is the reason why im getting the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241557/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-awthz-zei).

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using the format of my map wrong, which cause the error. it should be like this

```
folders:
- map: "D:/Projects/PhpPrograms/project1"
```

-- not this---

```
 - map: "D:\Projects\PhpPrograms\project1"
```